# Retrieving td value from tr that has certain other td value

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

Need to get the links from a td in rows that has a certain td value.

this is a tr in the table and I want to get the link from the div "Match" if the div "Home team" is of a certain value. There are many rows and I want to find every link that is matching. I have tried this and every time I only get the first row of the table. Here is the link https://wp.nif.no/PageTournamentDetailWithMatches.aspx?tournamentId=403373&seasonId=200937&number=all . Note that I translated some of the values to English in the examples below

```
homegames = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-title = "Home team"]/a[text()="Cleveland"]//parent::div//parent::td//parent::tr')

for link in homegames:
    print(link.find_element_by_xpath('//td[3]/div/a').get_attribute('href'))
```

````
<td><div data-title="Date">23.10.2021</div></td>
<td><div data-title="Tid">16:15</div></td>
<td>div data-title="Matchnr">
        <a href="/MatchDetails?id=743062">2121503051</a>
</div>
</td><td><div data-title="Home team"><a href="/PageOrgDetail.aspx?LinkId=86613" title="Cleveland Basket - MEN 4">Cleveland</a></div></td>
<td><div data-title="Away team">
        <a href="/PageOrgDetail.aspx?LinkId=890549" title="SSK Ohio Basketball - MEN 3">Ohio Travellers</a></div></td>
<td><div data-title="Court"><a href="">F21</a></div></td><td><div data-title="Result">71 - 64</div></td>
<td><div data-title="Referee">John Doe<br>Will Smith<br></div></td></tr>```
````

Comment: can you share the url you are trying to pull this from?

Comment: Updated the post with link now

Comment: thanks. so with the provided url, you want all the data-title that matches what, and the that contain what text?

Comment: i want to get the link from the <a> within <div data-title 'Kampnr'> from every row that has data-title = "Hjemmelag" containing a value that I send to the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is within the html source (so no need to use Selenium). But regardless of using Selenium or not, what you can do here is let BeautifulSoup find the specific tags you are after.

Without Selenium, it requires a little manipulation as decode the html.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import html

keyword = 'Askim'

url = 'https://wp.nif.no/PageTournamentDetailWithMatches.aspx?tournamentId=403373&seasonId=200937&number=all'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

jsonStr = soup.find('div', {'class':'xwp_table_bg'}).find_next('input')['value']
jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)

links_list = []
for each in jsonData['data']:
    #each = jsonData['data'][6]
    htmlStr = ''.join(each)
    htmlStr = html.unescape(htmlStr)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlStr, 'html.parser')

    if soup.find('div', {'data-title':'Hjemmelag'}, text=keyword):
        link = soup.find('div', {'data-title':'Kampnr'}).find('a')['href']
        links_list.append(link)
```

Comment: yeah okey, this finds the links for all the rows. Lets say I only want to find the links where Hjemmelag is 'Askim'

Comment: just turn that into a variable. Check the edit I made

Comment: I get this error: link = line 23, in <module>                                                       soup.find('div', {'data-title':keyword}).find('a')['href']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: ah. fixed it. But there are no Askim I see in that data

Comment: the td for Hjemmelag that contains the value that i want as a variable(for example Askim, Askim is the text in that a tag inside that div while Askim IF is the value in title) is a sibling of the td with the link

Comment: Oh ok. I see. Give it shot now.

Comment: It works! Thank you. Did not need Selenium after all. I thought the table was hidden but apparently not